# Azure cloud service: two web role instances rebooted at the same time?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a web site hosted on Azure as a cloud service. It has a web role with two instances. The instances belong to one resource group and are **assigned to different update- and fault domains**, which in theory should prevent them from simultaneous reboot.

Some time ago we experienced a ten minutes long downtime and it seems that our both web role instances were rebooted at the same time.

*Azure management logs do not say anything relevant, the reboot logs are completely empty.*

1. Is this actually possible that both instances were restarted at the same time?
2. Why do "Reboot Logs" contain no information?
3. How can I check what really happened (any other logs somewhere)?
4. How can I prevent both instances from being rebooted at the same time?

Comment: Unless you had some type of software glitch in your role instances related to something like bad input data, you're right - two instances shouldn't be taken down simultaneously, especially when spanning fault- and update-domains. If you have a support contract, it might be worth opening a ticket.

Comment: You can check ETW events on the machines, those are the most accurate. I had several cases where I've found interesting things on the machine's event log that were missing from the Reboot & Management Logs.
Connect to the machine and open Event Viewer, then look in either 'Windows Logs --> Application' or 'Application and Services Logs --> Windows Azure'.